# File in directory cannot be found

Tags: objective-c, resources

Hopefully just a quick one. In XCode, trying to import a file called `cocos2d.h` and it is in my directory and copied across, not just the reference ie it was copied across to the projects directory. But when I try `#import "cocos2d.h"`, it says `'cocos2d.h'` file not found"

```
[[Error in red with the actual header file itself in view on the left directly next to it]]
```

Hopefully somebody knows what is going on here!!

[image: Error in red with the actual header file itself in view on the left directly next to it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I worked this one out the other day!
All you need to do is specify the folder so in this case

> ## import "cocos2d/cocos2d.h"

Hope this helps others out there!!